# AsyncOperationManager in a .net component for windows service

Tags: .net, multithreading, windows-services, components, synchronizationcontext

We have developed a .Net component which works great for WinForms. This component is using a `SynchronizationContext` to raise events from the underlying threads marshalling to the UI thread (of course the component would get the `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` automatically and use it to post the events to UI thread of application).

Now we want to create a nt service re-using this component. Since windows service does not provide a `SynchronizationContext` automatically, I thought we could use `AsyncOperationManager` (and its `SynchronizationContext`) in order to marshal all the events fired in the underlying threads of this components to a single processor thread. Would this be a good approach?

In my tests I used the call to `AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation(null);` from different threads to check the behavior of the posted async operations (one executing `MyService.OnStart()` method ... and another an internal processing thread which I run in my service). For my surprise the thread ID of the posted async operation was always the one executing the `MyService.OnStart()` method, so probably the SCM thread.

There is a lack of documentation on MSDN regarding this, but I thought the thread who calls `AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation` would be the one which the async operations will be marshalled to.

Could anyone shed some light here? Also, would you see something wrong with my intention of using this `AsyncOperationManager` in windows service? What are the other ways?

Comment: No, it is WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext that actually does the work.  You don't have one in a service.  You could get one by actually calling Application.Run() in a thread.

Comment: *Why* do you need a SynchronoizationContext at all?

Comment: @HansPassant: So, you don't think the AsyncOperationManager would be good for me? I know WinFormsSynchCtx does it in WinForms. In the service I would like to marshal all the events from the underlying threads of the component to only a single processor thread in an easy way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created my own threading model consisting of a processor thread which picks up requests from other threads and then creates back responses.